# xterm not rendering fonts correctly

Tags: terminal, xterm

I was trying to run a program in xterm but it displays fonts incorrectly. [See here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4FbL.png)

Here is my .Xresources

```
XTerm.vt100.locale: true
XTerm.vt100.metaSendsEscape: true
XTerm.vt100.backarrowKey: false
XTerm.ttyModes: erase ^?
XTerm.vt100.saveLines: 2048
XTerm.vt100.faceName: mononoki:size=10:antialias=false:scalable=true:spacing=mono
XTerm*locale: true
XTerm*renderFont: true
XTerm*forceBoxChars: true
XTerm.vt100.reverseVideo: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the picture is printed using U+2580 UPPER HALF BLOCK "▀" or U+2584 LOWER HALF BLOCK "▄" characters, with a proper choice of foreground and background color for each.

So far I haven't come across any font that defines the [Box drawing](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2500.pdf) and [Block elements](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2580.pdf) characters  (your ones are in the latter group) in a way that they pixel-perfectly align into the character grid of terminal emulators.

One thing you can do is to try other fonts, hopefully you'll have more luck than I and find one.

Another thing you might want to try: Certain terminal emulators (including VTE-based ones: GNOME Terminal, Tilix, ...; and Konsole) make an exception for these characters and draw them manually rather than taking from the font. This way they can guarantee that they align nicely.